# Computation of some Fourier/Hankel transforms

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I need to compute the Fourier transform of the following functions :

$$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{a + (1-|x_1|^2-|x_2|^2)^2}$$

where $a>0$ is a positive constant. I have seen that because this function is radially symmetric, one way to compute its Fourier transform is to compute the Hankel 0-th order of the function

$$g(r) = \frac{1}{a + (1-r^2)^2}$$

and then $\mathcal{F}(f) = 2\mathbb{H}_0(g)$.

There is book called ''Tables of Integral Transforms'' that treats some Hankel transforms (chapter 8) but I was unable to find a satisfying formula for my specific problem. My intuition is to maybe decompose the rational fraction into more simple fractions and then use a known formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following K.defaoite ideas, here is what I came up with :

$$g(r) = \frac{1}{2i\sqrt{a}}\bigg(\frac{1}{r^2-1 - i\sqrt{a}} - \frac{1}{r^2-1 + i\sqrt{a}}\bigg).$$

Now can find $b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $b^2 = -1-i\sqrt{a}$ and so can construct $h$ as
$$h(r) = 2i\sqrt{a}g(r) = \frac{1}{r^2+b^2} - \frac{1}{r^2+ (\overline{b})^2}$$

and so using the formula given by K.defaoite [http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~giacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/Piessens2000.pdf](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/Piessens2000.pdf) (can be found on the wikipedia page as well) we obtain that

$$\mathbb{H}_0(h)(x) = K_0(bx) - K_0(\overline{b}x).$$

But now, is there a way to explicitely compute this quantity ? I do not know enough about Bessel functions identities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the closest thing I could find.

There is a table of Hankel transforms [here](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/%7Egiacomo.dellariccia/Table%20of%20contents/Piessens2000.pdf) and they state that if
$$f(r)=\frac{r^\nu}{(r^2+a^2)^{\mu+1}}$$
That its $\nu$th order Hankel transform is
$$\mathcal{H}_\nu(f)(s)= \frac{s^\mu a^{\nu-\mu}}{2^\mu\Gamma(\mu+1)}K_{\nu-\mu}(as)$$

So i.e in the case $\nu=0,\mu=1,a=i$ you get
$$f(r)=\frac{1}{(1-r^2)^2}$$
So then
$$\mathcal{H}_0(f)(s)=\frac{-is}{2}K_{-1}\left(is\right)$$
And it is known
$$K_{-1}(is)=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(J_1(s)+iY_1(s)\right)$$

Perhaps try completing the square in the denominator? I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It gave me the idea to separate the fraction into two parts to obtain your formula. I posted the answer I obtained in the end.